# Which class can not be a subclass in java and why?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I am not getting this question correctly:

> Which class can not be a subclass in java and why?
>  a.) abstract
>   class
>  b.) parent class
>  c.) final class
>  d.) none of
>   them

Actually according to me a parent class can not be a subclass, but form http://www.mastguru.com i got the result that, "final class" can not be a subclass.
According to java standard we cant create sub class of a final class. So please suggest me and explain to clear my doubt.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 2):

Any of these can be a subclass. For example:

```
public class Superclass {
}

public abstract class AbstractSubclass extends Superclass {
}

public class MiddleClass extends Superclass {
}

public class BottomClass extends MiddleClass {
}

public final class FinalSubclass extends Superclass {
}
```

- `AbstractSubclass` is an example of a subclass which is abstract
- `MiddleClass` is an example of a "parent class" (by which it means superclass, I assume) which is also a subclass
- `FinalSubclass` is an example of a subclass which is final

Even `Superclass` isn't really needed here, as *any* class other than `java.lang.Object` is a subclass - either of `java.lang.Object` or of some (potentially indirect) subclass of `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 0):

A parent class can be a sub class of other class.

This is called **MultiLevel Inheritance**.

```
A->B->C
```

B can inherit A and C can inherit B.

Answer (score 0):

A parent class can be a subclass, being a parent class just entails that it has a subclass. For instance, `JComponent` is a subclass of `Object`, but it's still a parent class, because of its subclasses.

For instance, looking [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html), we see:

```
java.lang.Object
   extended by java.awt.Component
     extended by java.awt.Container
        extended by javax.swing.JComponent
```

so `JComponent` is  a subclass. But it also is a parent for classes such as `AbstractButton`, `BasicInternalFrameTitlePane`, `Box`, and so on.